# zlib.net 2 files with the same lengt resulting in 2 different final lenght after compressing

Tags: vb.net, zlib

is it normal for 2 files with the same length to have different lenghts after compressing there bytes using zlib.net on vb.net?

this is the compression module i use using zlib.net reference, the 2 files are almose the same, there are juste less than 100 bytes making the difference between them

```
Imports System.IO
Imports zlib

Module zlib_compression

    Public Sub CopyStream(ByRef input As System.IO.Stream, ByRef output As         System.IO.Stream)

        Dim num1 As Integer
        Dim buffer1 As Byte() = New Byte(2000 - 1) {}
        num1 = input.Read(buffer1, 0, 2000)
        Do While (num1 > 0)
            output.Write(buffer1, 0, num1)
            num1 = input.Read(buffer1, 0, 2000)
        Loop
        output.Flush()

    End Sub


    Public Function Compress(ByVal InputBytes As Byte()) As Byte()

        Using output As New MemoryStream
            Dim outZStream As Stream = New ZOutputStream(output,         zlib.zlibConst.Z_BEST_SPEED)
            Using input As Stream = New MemoryStream(InputBytes)
                CopyStream(input, outZStream)
                outZStream.Close()               'do not remove
                Return output.ToArray()
            End Using
        End Using

    End Function

    Public Function Decompress(ByVal InputBytes As Byte()) As Byte()

        Using output As New MemoryStream
            Using outZStream As Stream = New ZOutputStream(output)
                Using input As Stream = New MemoryStream(InputBytes)
                    CopyStream(input, outZStream)
                    Return output.ToArray()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

    End Function


End Module
```

Comment: Also when calling the functions(got this problem with decompress) from other modules, sometimes the copystream sub get stuck on the output.write line and the form1 stop responding

Comment: It is perfectly normal for different files to compress differently. You can even test that with a regular compression tool: create an unsorted list of words and compress it. Now sort it, and compress again. The second file will typically be smaller.

Comment: and for the error i get with the output.write line, when i use a loop in another module to decompress different files, how to solve that issue? it's says something about inflating it doesn't give much info

Comment: This is commonplace with compression algorithms. Some file types can be compressed more than others.

Comment: Suppose I have two text files: the first one is a 10000 characters excerpt from a book. The second one is 'e' repeated 10000 times. Which ones do you think would be smaller? The second one because it can be compressed to just e(10000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, yes.  In fact it is necessarily true.  It is not possible to losslessly compress all of the same length files to a smaller size, since there are not enough bits in the smaller size to identify all of the original files.  If some are compressed, then some must be expanded.

Comment: What aboute this problem   [Zlib.net loop decompressing get stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349922/zlib-net-loop-decompressing-get-stuck), do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I saw it.  This is not a code debugging site.  You need to post an actual question with what you have tried to remedy the problem and where you are stuck.